# Return code of a bash script being called from a Subprocess

Tags: python, bash, docker

I am writing a script that imports a bunch of data to a couchdb database, the issue is each db takes around 15 minutes, so I do not watch the whole thing as I have on average 20 db to import.

The script loops through an array of items, and then calls subprocess on each in order run the import before moving on to the next.

What I have tried to do is catch any db's that do not load correctly, by way of failed script.
I am trying to catch this when the return code is not 0, the issue is I can only get the return code of the subprocess calling the docker command, not if the script executes correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import subprocess

cities = ["x","y", "z"];

uncompletedcities = []
for x in cities:
    dockerscript = "docker exec -it docker_1 ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node --debug --presets es2015 app/exportToCouch %s %s" % (x,x)
    p = subprocess.Popen(dockerscript, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    error = p.communicate()
    if p.returncode != 0:
            uncompletedcities.append(x)

    while p.poll() == None:
        print p.stderr.read()

print (uncompletedcities)
```

so the issue is, I recieve the return code of

```
p = subprocess.Popen(dockerscript, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

not the return code of the script being called here

```
dockerscript = "docker exec -it docker_1 ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node --debug --presets es2015 app/exportToCouch %s %s" % (x,x)
```

so in essence, I want to go one deeper into the return code, and get the return code of the docker command that subprocess is calling, no the return code of subprocess.

So just to get the return code of this:

```
docker exec -it docker_1 ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node --debug --presets es2015 app/exportToCouch
```

Comment: The `p.returncode` attribute will contain the return code of the `docker exec ...` command.  There is no separate return code for `subprocess.Popen`.  Also, if you run `p.communicate()`, then don't run `p.poll()` or `p.stderr.read()` afterwards.

Comment: Is this more a question about what `docker exec` returns? You might want to add a docker tag and see what turns up.  Although, a quick google shows a lot of chatter on that topic already.

Comment: BTW, `shell=True` opens you up to serious security bugs here. If you had a city named `$(rm -rf $HOME)` in your data, you'd have that code executed *on the host*, not inside the Docker container. It's far safer to pass an explicit argv array to `subprocess.Popen()`, with `shell=False`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you run:

```
docker exec -it
```

your `-it` flags are doing something contrary to the point of what you are trying. You are trying to open an interactive session. This isn't actually *executing* the command.

You can remove both of these from your command and just run `docker exec`:

```
dockerscript = "docker exec docker_1 ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node --debug --presets es2015 app/exportToCouch %s %s" % (x,x)
```

For what it's worth I would probably look into using [docker-py](https://github.com/docker/docker-py), too. It's a lot more flexible for running docker commands if you end up with more than just a few command line docker commands. It also lets you avoid `shell=true`.

Comment: sorry, i named it dockerimage_1 just to hide the real name, it is in fact a container.

Comment: not fully, I was just on vacation so didnt work on it, back at it now, if this helps I'll accept your answer.